# Vue data Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

When I create an array, and push data into it. It turns into a proxy and I can't use JS array functions on them anymore.

```
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: { PokeList, FilterType, SearchPokemon},
  data() {
        return {
            pokemons: [],
            numOfPokemon: 151,
            types: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async prepairPokeIds() {
            for (let i = 1; i <= this.numOfPokemon; i++){
                
                await this.fetchPokemonData(i)
            }
        },
        async fetchPokemonData(id) {      
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
            const data = await res.json()
            this.types.push(data.types[0].type.name)
            this.pokemons.push(data)
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        },
        async test(){
          console.log(this.types.length)
        }
    },
  async created() {
      this.prepairPokeIds()
      await this.test()
      console.log(this.pokemons)
      console.log(this.types)
  }
}
</script>
```

The console.log inside the test functions returns a value of 0 even though I have data inside the proxy target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below code:

```
async created() {
  this.prepairPokeIds() // sends a request and executes line below
  await this.test()
  console.log(this.pokemons)
  console.log(this.types)
}
```

`this.prepairPokeIds()` will fire off the first request in loop, control comes back to `created` and it'll execute `await this.test()`
which immediately executes `console.log(this.types.length)`, so you get 0 which is the value at the time.

---

Code below should log proper value since it executes after first request is resolved.

```
async prepairPokeIds() {
   for (let i = 1; i <= this.numOfPokemon; i++){      
     await this.fetchPokemonData(i)
     console.log(this.types.length)
   }
},
```

Or you can return a promise(s) from `prepairPokeIds()` and await it before executing `this.test()`